# Switch Between if statements

Tags: php

I have a simple conditional, but I need to use different variables based on another variable.

Pseudo code:

```
if $check == 1, use this line:
  if ($a == 1 && $b == 2 && $c == 3) {
else use this line:
  if ($a == 1 && $b == 2) {
... huge amount of code that does not change I do not want to repeat it, if possible
  } //end conditional
```

Update:  Is there a way to combine the conditional params into a single statement?

Comment: ...So what's your *question*?

Comment: Is there a way to change the conditional parameters?, based on a variable

Comment: So? Just use a secon level of if clause? if $check == 1 { if...{} else{} elseif $check == 2 { ...}

Comment: @errorinpersona  I don't understand how to set different conditions - could you please use my example.

Comment: @parti I think it would be better not to write pseudo code, but your actual use case. errorinpersona's answer seems to be exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your conditional to:

```
if ($a == 1 && $b == 2 && ($check != 1 || $c == 3)) {
```

If `$check == 1`, the condition will check that `$c == 3`. If `$check != 1`, the condition will ignore the value of `$c`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, that seems to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
if check == 1 {
    if ($a == 1 && $b == 2 && $c == 3){
        //do some stuff
    } elseif ($a == 1 && $b == 2) {
      // do some other stuff
    }
} elseif check == 2 {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
if check == 1 {
    if ($a == 1 && $b == 2 && $c == 3) {
        //do something
    }
} else {
    if ($a == 1 && $b == 2) {
        //huge code
    }
}
```

Comment: No, where you have the ... is a huge amount of code that I don't want to repeat.  And you could remove both of the else statements as they aren't needed.

Comment: Maybe just explain what exactly you want. I just described how you can you an if clause inside an if clause which seems to fit your need. Sure enough you have to fit this to your needs... .

Comment: Ok, I'll try again:  I want to write either this beginning conditional: 'if ($a == 1 && $b == 2 && $c == 3) {'  OR this beginning conditional: 'if ($a == 1 && $b == 2) {'

Comment: @errorinpersona there's a missing `}` before `elseif`